# How to view process history to analyse the memory bottleneck?

Tags: linux, process, memory, forensics

Yesterday my billing db got crashed due to high memory usage.

Now would like to see what are all the processes running when the db got crashed. Is there any way to  look into this ? Please help..

Answer (score -1):

Just open terminal and type this command:

```
ps aux
```

It will list all processes and how much memory it's using.

Comment: This shows what is running now. The question is what was running at the time of the crash.